# Switching from spousal benefit to my own and then back to spousal

Tags: united-states, retirement, social-security

I started collecting SS at 66 (my full retirement age), my wife started collecting SS (spousal benefit) at 66 (her full retirement age).

If my wife switches to her own benefit at 70, and then I pass away first, will she be allowed to return to the spousal benefit and collect 100% of my benefit?

Comment: I am not sure if she can switch back to the spousal benefit once she changes from spousal to her own benefit.

Comment: There is some discussion of the options here -- https://www.kiplinger.com/article/retirement/T051-C000-S004-maximize-the-social-security-spousal-benefit.html/ . It seems to stop short of the "switch and then switch back" strategy you are asking about, but it might give you some insight.

Comment: After reading Kiplinger, I'm left with the idea that social security will give her the higher of her own benefit or 50% of mine.  But I am not so sure they will do that.

Comment: I'm keeping my fingers crossed.  They may be better organized than I give them credit for.